# Laravel: Can't access variable in view sent from controller@update

Tags: php, laravel

I can't find the reason why... but **I can't get my var and any other**.
**Function** actually **save the data and validates fine**, then sends back to the edit view with new data too, **but I can't reach my** `$success` **variable**...

`CourseController@update:`

```
class CourseController extends Controller {

    public function update( Request $request, Course $course ) {
        // Validates data or return to view with errors
        $request->validate( Course::$validation_rules );

        // Pass: Gets the record from db or returns 404
        $course = Course::findOrFail( $course->id );

        // Update the course
        $course->name = Str::ucfirst( $request->name );
        $course->description = Str::ucfirst( $request->description );

        // Save the data
        $course->save();

        // Redirect to view with success
        return redirect()->route( 'courses.edit', $course )
            ->with( 'success', 'Cambios guardados.' ) // problem here? where?
        ;
    }
}
```

`Course (model):`

```
class Course extends Model {

    public static $validation_rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

`edit.blade.php (portion):`

```
{{-- some code before --}}

    @if ( $errors->any() )
        @foreach ( $errors->all() as $error )
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                <strong class="d-block"> {{ $error }} </strong>

                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    @elseif ( $success ?? false )
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $success }}</strong>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    @endif

{{-- some code after --}}
```

That's what i have currently. It is extremely weird, I always get null from `$success` and any other I try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `$success` variable is flashed in the session when you redirect using `with`.

In view file you should use

```php
@elseif (session('success'))
```

Reference in official documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: Now works! but I can't understand why. I have the same portion of code in another view (same procedure way) and I get the value by `$success` successfully... any explanation for this behavior?

Comment: I don't know, may be the target route also return an `$success` variable to the view.

Comment: But I tried changing the variable name and even not worked...

Comment: If you dont mind, can you put the code in the https://gist.github.com/, i can help you finding why